# Cassandra: How to increase the number of node instances in localhost

Tags: docker, cassandra-2.0

I am able to start two cassandra node instances up and running through docker.

```
docker run --name n1 -d tobert/cassandra -dc DC1 -rack RAC1
docker run --name n2 -d tobert/cassandra -seeds 172.17.0.2 -dc DC2 -rack RAC1
```

When I try to start the new node instance n3, then it doesn't through any error but I do no see any n3 instance came up, I am seeing only 2 nodes.

```
$ docker run --name n3 -d tobert/cassandra -seeds 172.17.0.2 -dc DC1 -rack RAC2
XXX

$ docker ps (doesnt show the third cassandra node)
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                               NAMES
8ab64fa86819        tobert/cassandra    "/bin/cassandra-docke"   41 minutes ago      Up 41 minutes       7000/tcp, 7199/tcp, 9042/tcp, 9160/tcp, 61621/tcp   n2
125fc4ffba4d        tobert/cassandra    "/bin/cassandra-docke"   42 minutes ago      Up 42 minutes       7000/tcp, 7199/tcp, 9042/tcp, 9160/tcp, 61621/tcp   n1

$ docker exec -it n1 nodetool status
Datacenter: DC2
===============
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address     Load       Tokens  Owns (effective)  Host ID  Rack
UN  172.17.0.3  82.43 KB   256     100.0%            XXX      RAC1
Datacenter: DC1
===============
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address     Load       Tokens  Owns (effective)  Host ID  Rack
UN  172.17.0.2  51.48 KB   256     100.0%            XXX      RAC1
```

Will anyone please let me know why is this happening. What conf need to be done to initiate more node instances. It is clear that the node instances more than 2 in my localhost is an issue here. Why?

Comment: stdout is logged to `/data/log/output.log` which is a volume in that image. `docker inspect -f '{{.Mounts | printf "%+v" }}' n1`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like sometimes we need to run the `docker run` command more than once in-order to start-up the new node. No idea why this happens.

I have assigned memory of 4GB to the docker container using command `boot2docker --memory 4096 init` which gave some space to add a new node which I was expecting to.

Finally here are the nodes that are up and running

```
$ docker exec -it n1 nodetool status
Datacenter: DC1
===============
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address     Load       Tokens  Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack
UN  172.17.0.3  98.91 KB   256     64.5%             30156883-aafe-43b8-b8ee-fec2c9225778  RAC2
UN  172.17.0.2  51.51 KB   256     68.3%             486f457c-8be2-4844-9cd0-d5ef37b46cea  RAC1
UN  172.17.0.4  98.97 KB   256     67.3%             d19ad6a1-8138-4283-815c-3b223a33c987  RAC1
```